# Magic 8 Ball not printing all the time java

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, boolean

I'm trying to make my code run 100% of the time by the percents I added. The percents are listed by the boolean values. I am new to java and would take any help. This is my code my it doesn't run all the time as a magic 8 ball should
My code.

```
public class Assessment_Unit_1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean good = Math.random() < .13;
    boolean notNow = Math.random() < .37;
    boolean yes = Math.random() < .24;
    boolean never = Math.random() < .26;
    System.out.println("You rolled the Magic 4 Ball:");
    System.out.println("All Signs Say:");
    if (good) {
        System.out.println("Prospects Good");
    }
    else if (notNow) {
        System.out.println("Not now");
    }

    else if (yes) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }

    else if (never) {
        System.out.println("never");
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: question is not clear. please edit your question

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call Math.Random() it returns a **new** value between 0 and 1. Therefore it is possible the first `math.random()` returns greater than 0.13 and the next one a different number greater than 0.37, the next math.random() a value greater than 0.24 and the next one another different value which could be greater than 0.26...

If you changed the if else statement to just if statements, it is possible it could output more than one answer! This is clearly not what you want.

You only want one outcome right? With the chances of 13% 37% 24% and 26%, that's my assumption. Your code logic is a little off. Following your code structure, you need to define a single variable that you check four times such as `double rndDecimal = math.random()` then, check if `rndDecimal > 0 && rndDecimal < 0.13 for the first boolean` or for the second it is between 0.13 and 0.5 (0.13 + 0.37) and then between 0.5 and 0.74 next 0.74 and 1! That will always give you a result

Comment: @MarkSeibert If you think this is the correct answer it would be great if you clicked the check mark beside the answer to mark it as correct :)